# Prove a large number of congruences MOD P

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$P$ is prime, we know the Wilson's Theorem $(P-1)!≡-1 \pmod P$.
It seams that many of the sums in $[1,P-1]$ with $P-1$ factors $≡-1 \pmod P$.

$A,B,C$ is positive integer.
$${1^A}{2^B} + {2^A}{3^B} + ... + {(P - 2)^A}{(P - 1)^B} \equiv  - 1\pmod P,A + B = P - 1$$
$${1^A}{3^B} + {2^A}{4^B} + ... + {(P - 3)^A}{(P - 1)^B} + {(P - 1)^A}{1^B} \equiv  - 1\pmod P,A + B = P - 1$$
$${1^A}{4^B} + {2^A}{5^B} + ... + {(P - 4)^A}{(P - 1)^B} + {(P - 2)^A}{1^B} + {(P - 1)^A}{2^B} \equiv  - 1\pmod P,A + B = P - 1$$
$${1^A}{2^B}{3^C} + {2^A}{3^B}{4^C} + ... + {(P - 3)^A}{(P - 2)^B}{(P - 1)^C} \equiv  - 1\pmod P,A + B + C = P - 1$$
...and so on.
If number of factors $<P-1,0<A+B<P-1,0<A+B+C<p-1$, all of the sums $≡0 \pmod  P$.
$${1^2}{3^4} + {2^2}{4^4} + {3^2}{5^4} + {4^2}{6^4} + {5^2}{7^4} + {6^2}{1^4} = {\text{87527}} \equiv  - 1\pmod 7$$
$${1^2}{3^3} + {2^2}{4^3} + {3^2}{5^3} + {4^2}{6^3} + {5^2}{7^3} + {6^2}{1^3} = {\text{13475}} \equiv 0\pmod 7$$
Are they correct? If correct, where can I find the proof?

Comment: You really should look into formatting on this website, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. 

That said, let me talk about your first conjecture. It is false as stated, i.e. if you allow $A=0$ or $B=0$. For example, for $p=3$, $A=0$ and $B=2$, we get $1^0\cdot 2^2 = 4$, and $4\not\equiv -1$ mod $3$. However, a quick brute-force check seems to agree with you when $A,B>0$. I'll think some more about it.

Comment: In your example ,it is $1^2+2^2≡-1MOD 3$, I modify it,let A,B,C>0

Comment: The first conjecture holds for all primes less than $1000$, with all exponents $A,B>0$.

Comment: I posted an answer but found a mistake and deleted it. I've fixed the mistake and undeleted the answer, hopefully everything is correct now.

Comment: Tip to OP: `\pmod p` renders $\pmod p$.

Answer (score 2):

I've proven the first conjecture. It seems likely that the other conjectures will follow from a similar method, I will leave that to you.

Let $p$ be any prime. Define $S_p(B) = \sum_{k=2}^{p-1} (k-1)^{p-1-B}k^B$. This is your sum, just slightly rewritten, using that $A=p-1-B$. Below we will constantly be using $a^{p-1}=1$ mod $p$.

First, a note: If we take $B=0$, the sum transforms into $S_p(0) = \sum_{k=2}^{p-1}1\cdot 1 = p-2$, so $S_p(0)\equiv -2$ mod $p$.

Now, a **Lemma**: For $1\leq t\leq p-2$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^t = 0$ mod $p$.

*Proof:* Recalling the fact that the multiplicative group mod $p$ is cyclic, i.e. we have a primitive element $g$, we may rewrite this sum mod $p$ as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^t = \sum_{m=1}^{p-1}(g^m)^t = \sum_{m=1}^{p-1}(g^t)^m = \frac{g^{t(p-1)}-1}{g^t-1}.$$

As $p-1\not\mid t$, the denominator is not $0$ mod $p$, and so is invertible. The numerator, however, is $0$ mod $p$, and so the entire sum is $0$ mod $p$. This completes the proof.

**Proposition**. For $1\leq B\leq p-2$, we have $S_p(B)\equiv -1$ mod $p$.

*Proof:* Applying the binomial theorem to the first term of the product in the sum, we get
$$S_p(B) = \sum_{k=2}^{p-1} \sum_{n=0}^{p-1-B}\binom{p-1-B}{n}(-1)^{p-1-B-n}k^{n+B} =  \sum_{n=0}^{p-1-B}\binom{p-1-B}{n}(-1)^{p-1-B-n}\sum_{k=2}^{p-1}k^{n+B}.$$

Now, $n+B$ satisfies the criteria for the lemma in all cases except the case $n=p-1-B$. In this singular case, the sum is $p-2$, as seen above the lemma, and in all other cases, it is $-1$ mod $p$, by subtracting $1$ on both sides in the lemma. Thus, we get mod $p$ that

$$S_p(B) = p-2 - \sum_{n=1}^{p-1-B}\binom{p-1-B}{n}(-1)^{p-1-B-n}.$$

Now, the latter can be recognized as the binomial theorem applied to $(1-1)^{p-1-B}$, which is of course $0$, but missing the first term for $n=0$. This term is $1$, and so we get that

$$S_p(B) = p-2-(-1) = p-1 \equiv -1 \mod p.$$

This completes the proof.